# C# Entity Framework Core If-statements doesnt work

Tags: c#, if-statement, entity-framework-core

i run into a problem with if statements together with EFCore...

i have no Data in my DB so my If-Statements should not be skipped over...

Do i have the if-statements wrong?

Example:
I want to say. If any IP-Address in DB has the same Address like the new IP-Address, dont create a new IP-Address Dataset.

and that also with Interfaces and Gateways...

The Problem are these IF's:

```
            foreach (var iface in JsonNode.Ifaces ?? Enumerable.Empty<Iface>())
            {
                IfaceEntity NewIface = new IfaceEntity()
                {
                    Name = iface.Name,
                    Macaddress = iface.Macaddress
                };
                foreach (var addrs in iface.Addrs ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                {
                    AddrsEntity NewAddrs = new AddrsEntity()
                    {
                        Address = addrs
                    };
                    if (context.Addresses.Any(n => n.Address != addrs)) 
                    { 
                        NewIface.Addrs.Add(NewAddrs); 
                    };
                }
                foreach (var gateway in iface.Gateway ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                {
                    GatewayEntity NewGateway = new GatewayEntity()
                    {
                        Address = gateway
                    };
                    if (context.Gateways.Any(n => n.Address != gateway)) 
                    { 
                        NewIface.Gateway.Add(NewGateway); 
                    };
                }
                if (context.Ifaces.Any(n => n.Macaddress != iface.Macaddress)) 
                { 
                    NewNode.Interfaces.Add(NewIface); 
                };
```

These are a small part of the full Enitity:

```
[Table("nodemon_Iface")]
public class IfaceEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int IfaceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AddrsEntity> Addrs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GatewayEntity> Gateway { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Macaddress { get; set; }
    public int NodeEntityId { get; set; }
    public NodeEntity NodeEntity { get; set; }
}


[Table("nodemon_Addrs")]
public class AddrsEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int AddrsEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int IfaceId { get; set; }
    public IfaceEntity IfaceEntity { get; set; }
}

[Table("nodemon_Gateway")]
public class GatewayEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int GatewayEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int IfaceId { get; set; }
    public IfaceEntity IfaceEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your tests appear backward. You are saying if exists any row with a non-matching address, add the new address. What you want to say is if not exists Any row with an equal address, or if all addresses do not match.

Comment: yeah i want to say. is there any row in the table with the sam adress like the new one  then dont add the new one, if there isnt any adress like the new one then add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Ah i think the solution was

```
                    if (!context.Gateways.Any(n => n.Address == gateway)) 
                    { 
                        NewIface.Gateway.Add(NewGateway); 
                    };
```